# Represent decimal numbers using integers

Tags: c, math

I'm trying to come up with a way of solving my hardware limitations using software. The problem I have is that I can only write whole numbers (integers) to my hardware, but I want the luxury of using decimal-numbers when calculating results etc.

HexaDecimals with a conversion-factor came to mind here.. I can techniqually send a hex-value like (00)**1105** and then just interpret that as 11.05 (E^-2) software side.

> This would mean that I techniqually could handle decimal numbers software side while only sending whole numbers to my hardware.

Are there better ways of dealing with this problem? *(Binary values are not an option since there is a length-limit of the messages that can be sent. **(length <= 10)**. I will not exceed E^5 (nnnnn) for the intended use.)*

This current approach has obvious problems and all approaches will likely have that **but** I'm curious as to what other ways this could be achieved?

Don't worry about the hardware, just consider it a black box, where integer-numbers are the only valid input.

Comment: If it is not necessary, I would abstain from using some floating-point implementation. What is the range of integers the hardware can handle? What is the range of decimal numbers you need to represent?

Comment: The hardware may be a "black box" but, presumably, you want to send values to it so some operations are performed and results produced.   Such information is critical to deciding what approach is "best", but you have provided no such information.

Comment: if your _int_ are on 32b you can send the 32b of a _float_ as an _int_ (I don't speak about conversion), same for 64b _double_ if for instance you have _long_ on 64b

Comment: can't you store the integer and the decimal part separately? Like in a structure `struct deci{ int integer,decimal;}d;` create a conversion function and work with decimals.

Comment: Why do you think, that interpreting hexadecimal values as decimal values is a good way? Hexadecimal is only a string representation, so this implicit conversion to decimal seems very arbitrary. Why not use decimal values and set a fixed point somewhere (i.e. 100 is 1.00)

Comment: what means "I can only write whole numbers (integers) to my hardware" ? can you do floating computation on your hardware or not ? There are floating computation library whose do not use FPU, no need to reinvent the wheel

Comment: What exactly can be sent in a message? (At most) 10 bytes of any value? A string of (up to) 10 hexadecimal digits? Something else?...

Comment: What are you supposed to to with the values? Are you performing calculations on them? Only storing them? Receiving and sending them from or to some external device? Presenting them to a user through a display? And many compilers have built-in support to *emulate* floating-point datatypes like `float`. If you need to perform calculations there are libraries which does fixed-point arithmetic using integers, and then you can convert that to a `float` for presentation?

Comment: @Joel your question is unclear and you do not answer to all the remarks ...

Comment: @Joel I think you need to tell us more about those numbers and about your blackbox. Otherwise it's impossible to give any correct hint. I'll close vote "unclear what you're asking" in 30 minutes if there won't be any substantial clarifications in your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From what I can understand from the question, fixed points might help you.
Fixed points allow you to do decimal arithmetic with integers assuming the number of digits after the decimal point is known in advance.

Here is a quick and dirty implemetation of fixed points:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define FP_ABS(x) ((x) >= 0 ? (x) : -(x))

// This will determine the number of digits after the decimal point.
// It must be a power of 10.
// In this case, you can represent all the numbers in the range -2147483.648 to 2147483.647
// or if you want to be safe -2000000.000 to 2000000.000
#define FP_DECIMAL_FACTOR 1000

#define FP_LIT(x) ((int)((x) * FP_DECIMAL_FACTOR))
#define FP_ADD(x, y) ((x) + (y))
#define FP_SUB(x, y) ((x) - (y))
#define FP_MUL(x, y) ((x) * (y) / FP_DECIMAL_FACTOR)
#define FP_DIV(x, y) ((x) * FP_DECIMAL_FACTOR / (y))

#define FP_INT_PART(x) ((x) / FP_DECIMAL_FACTOR)
#define FP_DEC_PART(x) (FP_ABS((x) % FP_DECIMAL_FACTOR))


int main()
{
    int a = FP_LIT(25.01);
    int b = FP_LIT(12.2);

    printf("a = %d.%03d\n", FP_INT_PART(a), FP_DEC_PART(a));
    printf("b = %d.%03d\n", FP_INT_PART(b), FP_DEC_PART(b));

    int a_plus_b = FP_ADD(a, b);
    printf("a + b = %d.%03d\n", FP_INT_PART(a_plus_b), FP_DEC_PART(a_plus_b));

    int a_minus_b = FP_SUB(a, b);
    printf("a - b = %d.%03d\n", FP_INT_PART(a_minus_b), FP_DEC_PART(a_minus_b));

    int b_minus_a = FP_SUB(b, a);
    printf("b - a = %d.%03d\n", FP_INT_PART(b_minus_a), FP_DEC_PART(b_minus_a));

    int a_multiply_b = FP_MUL(a, b);
    printf("a * b = %d.%03d\n", FP_INT_PART(a_multiply_b), FP_DEC_PART(a_multiply_b));

    int a_divide_b = FP_DIV(a, b);
    printf("a / b = %d.%03d\n", FP_INT_PART(a_divide_b), FP_DEC_PART(a_divide_b));

    int b_divide_a = FP_DIV(b, a);
    printf("b / a = %d.%03d\n", FP_INT_PART(b_divide_a), FP_DEC_PART(b_divide_a));

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Good suggestion. Beware that `FP_MUL` and `FP_DIV` should use `long long` arithmetics to reduce the possibilities for arithmetic overflow producing incorrect results.

Answer (score 1):

you are not clear at all, if you just need to do floating point computation without FPU just use libs like [Floating-point Library for Integer Processors](http://flip.gforge.inria.fr/)

Answer (score 0):

I remember I did something similar in an exam. I think it depends on the application.

For numerical processing you can do something like this:

- scale all numbers in the range [-1;1] by subtracting the mean values and dividing by the maximum of the modules. In this way multiplications will belong to the same range
- Multiply all the numbers by a power of 2 depending on your architecture (`2^32` or `2^64` for example)
- Round the values to integer
- Do your operations
- Rescale the values by dividing by the power of 2
- Bring the numbers back in the original range

I will give you further details as soon as I can.